# Adding transparent Gif images to list view in c#

Tags: c#, listview, transparency, gif

I am trying to add a transparent Gif image to list view, I used the following code snippet
to add gif image.

```
// control as ListView 
void AddGiftoListView(Control parent)
{
    Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.madLoader; // Transparent gif image
    Size sz = img.Size;
    PictureBox pbGif = new PictureBox();
    pbGif.Size = img.Size;
    pbGif.Image = img;

    parent.Controls.Add(pbGif);
    Point p = new Point(1, 1);
    pbGif.Location = p;
    pbGif.Show();
}
```

But the gif is not transparent, when the list view filled with text, we can see gif on top of that with white background. is there any way ro resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Shiju P K

Answer (score 0):

Try making your form's **TransparencyKey** as white

```
this.TransparencyKey = Color.White;
```